# Functionality for Updating Entities Using NSXMLParser and Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, nsxmlparser

I'm using NSXMLParser and Core Data to parse a feed and add/update entities using core data in my IPhone app.

The issue is that the feed contains new and update data, so once I parse the feed the following happens:

1. Create a new Entity
2. Populate the Entities Properties using NSXMLParser
3. In didEndElement, fetch entities already in the system with myEntityId equal to the Entity we parsed.
4. If there is more than 1 Entity, then delete the old ones as the feed passed us new data.
5. Save the Entity

My issue is that it seems like a lot of work to save update information, and the code also always creates a new record rather than just updating a current record.

Is there anyway that this process can be made simpler and avoid the need to create a new entity and delete the old one when doing an update?

My abbreviated code is as follows:

DidStartElement

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement...
{
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AnEntity"])
  {
    NSManagedObject *newEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    self.currentEntityObject = newEntity;
  } else 
  {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Title"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"MyEntityId"])
    {
      self.currentProperty = [NSMutableString string];
    }  
  }
}
```

DidEndElement

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement...
{
  if (self.currentEntityObject)
  {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Title"]) 
    {
      [self.currentEntityObject setValue:self.currentProperty forKey:@"title"];

    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"MyEntityId"]) 
    {
      [self.currentEntityObject setValue:self.currentProperty forKey:@"myEntityId"];

    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"AnEntity"])
    {
      [self.currentEntityObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastUpdated"];

      NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
      NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
      [request setEntity:entity];

      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(myEntityId = %@)", [self.currentEntityObject valueForKey:@"myEntityId"]];
      [request setPredicate:predicate];

      NSError *error = nil;
      NSArray *array = [_context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

      int countOfEntityId = array.count;

      if (array != nil && countOfEntityId > 1)
      {
        // This is an update so remove old versions
        for(int i=0; i < countOfEntityId; i++)
        {
          if(self.currentEntityObject != [array objectAtIndex:i])
          {
            [_context deleteObject:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
          } 
        } 
      }

      error = nil;
      [_context save:&error];

      self.currentEntityObject = nil;
    }
  }
}
```

FoundCharacters

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.currentProperty) 
    {
      [currentProperty appendString:string];
    }
}
```

My issue is that it seems like a lot of work to save update information, and it also always creates a new record rather than just updating a current record.

Is there anyway that this process can be made simpler and avoid the need to create a new entity and delete the old one when doing an update?

Any advice would be great.

Thanks 
Rich

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post but I'll answer anyways.

You should definitely check out Saul Mora's [MagicRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). He made it dead easy to use in any project, works with ARC/non-ARC automatically, and the setup of CoreData is a one liner.

First off I'll show you how I parse and update.

```
- (void)setUpBeforeParsing
{
    self.currentAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    self.currentParsedCharacterData = [NSMutableString string];

    self.currentParsedBatch = [NSMutableArray array];

    self.attributesDictionary = myManagedObjectObject.entity.attributesByName;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement...
{
    for (NSString *attribute in self.attributesDictionary) 
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:attribute]) 
        {
            accumulatingParsedCharacterData = YES;

            [self.currentParsedCharacterData setString:@""];
        }
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement...
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"myIdentifierThatObjectIsDone"]) 
    {
        [self.currentParsedBatch addObject:[self.currentAttributes copy]];
        [self.currentAttributes removeAllObjects];
        accumulatingParsedCharacterData = NO;
    }
    for (NSString *attribute in self.attributesDictionary) 
    {
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:attribute]) 
        {
            accumulatingParsedCharacterData = NO;

            [self.currentAttributes setObject:[self.currentParsedCharacterData copy] forKey:attribute];
        }
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    if (self.accumulatingParsedCharacterData) [self.currentParsedCharacterData appendString:string];
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    [MyCoreDataClass MR_importFromArray:self.currentParsedBatch];
}
```

Really the main thing to take from this is that you can build an array of dictionaries that carry values that you want to transfer to your managed objects. A guy named Tom Harrington wrote a demo on cimgf.com about naming your object's properties the same as the xml or json returned and then you can simply iterate through your properties until it matches the xml element returned. The beauty here is say somewhere down the line you want to save more of the returned xml to your objects, simply add a property to your object and the parser will automatically sync it.

At the end of parsing you will notice a class method called, this is from the MagicalRecord framework. As long as you set a 'relatedByAttribute' in the user info part of your data model then it will automatically sync the dictionaries to your managed objects. So if your objects have a unique identifying property called "MyEntityId" then in the user info dictionary of your entity set 'relatedByAttribute' - 'MyEntityId' and MagicalRecord takes care of it.

Let me know if you need any clarification.